# Resize paper to mbox

Tags: pdftex, paper-size

Is it possible to define a function where the page is resized to exactly the dimension of an mbox? For example, I want to do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\mbox{\Huge buffer}
\end{document}
```

And have the output be a PDF whose dimension are exactly the size of the bounding box around the word "buffer". Currently, I am using the program `pdfcrop` to trim the resulting image, but this is a hack. I was wondering if there was a way to do this in TeX natively.

Comment: How does LaTeXiT do this?

Comment: See also: [pdflatex: fit-page-to-contents or scale-contents-to-fit-page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12433/2975) as well as [Can I make the page as big as my picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13349/2975).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use something like:

```
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{stuff goes here}
\pdfhorigin=0pt
\pdfvorigin=0pt
\pdfpagewidth=\wd\mybox
\pdfpageheight=\ht\mybox
\advance\pdfpageheight by \dp\mybox
\shipout\box\mybox
```

But it works for PDFTeX/LuaTeX only.

Comment: BTW, ConTeXt has a `\startTEXpage \stopTEXpage` that does exactly that.

Comment: I think this can be made to work for all engines by using something like `\voffset=-1in \hoffset=-1in` instead.

Comment: @Will: I'm sure it can, but I certainly don't know how, if you have a working piece of code I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 6):

For the type of things that you seem to be doing, perhaps you might also want to look at the [preview](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview) package. The \mbox isn't necessary, and it gives you a way to make a series of properly trimmed images, in a single run.

Comment: I think this is the best option here!

Comment: `preview`'s definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `standalone` class with either the `preview` or `crop` option.
The first was the default for v0.x and uses the `preview` package.
The second is new with v1.0 and the default for v1.x.
It boxes the content and resizes the page to fit it.
This works similar to Khaled Hosny's answer but works with LaTeX in many flavors: `latex` (DVI mode), `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}% Add maybe `crop` or `preview` manually
\begin{document}
\mbox{\Huge buffer}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one with eplain, and I think this form of `\special` works only with XeTeX:

```
\input eplain
\hoffset=-1in
\voffset=-1in
\hruledefaultheight=0pt
\hruledefaultdepth=0pt
\vruledefaultwidth=0pt
\boxitspace=1pt % amount of whitespace on all sides
\setbox0\boxit{\hbox{This content right here will be the whole page.}}
\special{papersize=\the\wd0,\the\ht0}
\box0
\bye
```