# pdflatex: fit-page-to-contents or scale-contents-to-fit-page

Tags: pdftex, scaling, paper-size

I have a problem which can be solved one of two ways:

1. Typeset a given chunk of TeX in an "infinitely wide" space, then scale the result so that its width is the width of the page.
2. Typeset a given chunk of TeX in an "infinitely wide" space, then set the page size to the width of the result.

Can anybody suggest how to do this with pdflatex?  Unfortunately I can't use other TeXes like XeTeX, etc.

Comment: FWIW, my document consists of several display-mode math ($$xyz$$) elements which are extremely wide, and nothing else.  This appears to make the problem more difficult: many of the packages designed for this purpose can't use math-mode stuff in the detection of the proper page dimensions.

Comment: Second question is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452/250119.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. can be done using the `graphics` package and `\resizebox{\paperwidth}{!}{<content>}`
2. can be done using the `preview` package (or with the `standalone` class using it). You need to set the preview border to 0 for that. For overly large material use:

   ```
   \usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
   ```

   to set the page size first to maximum.

Comment: Hrm, neither of these work if the contents are larger than the page size.  For example, I tried `\usepackage[paperwidth=200in,centering]{geometry}\usepackage[displaymath,tightpage,active]{preview}\begin{preview}` and the page is still 200in wide.  Removing the `\usepackage{geometry}` crops off the sides of my content.

Comment: Perhaps I ought to mention that my document consists only of display-mode ("$$xyz$$") maths which are very wide, and nothing else.  I need to set the page width based on the math -- there's no text body to use.

Comment: @Adam: You should have mentioned that it is display math from the beginning. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/crop-equations-with-preview-package/13983#13983 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13213/can-i-make-the-page-as-big-as-my-picture/13214#13214.

Comment: Sorry!  At the time I didn't know it made a difference.