# Crop equations with preview package

Tags: equations, graphics, preview

Is it possible to avoid left space from equations previewed with preview package?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
\[x=3+y^2\]
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like a clipped (cropped?) equation. Is it possible?

Do you know a better solution to extract equations as images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [pdfcrop](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) Perl script.

Comment: I didn't know about it, thanks. It crops every page, so I still need package preview to produce pages with one mathematical expression on them. After that pdftk can split the document in individual pages.

Comment: the preview package will generate one equation per page, and pdftk can split them into one file per page. The command is `pdftk latex_output.pdf burst`.

Comment: Unless you absolutely require "real" displayed math and cannot use inline ones, MartinScharrer's answer is more preferable as `pdfcrop` is very slow can easily double the time it takes to generate the images.

Answer (score 11):

The left space is caused by the display style. You could use in-text style (`$ ... $` or `\( ... \)`) instead and use `\displaystyle` in it to get the same result without the space. You need to wrap the equation manually in a `preview` environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
$\displaystyle x=3+y^2$
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Even shorter would be the use of the `standalone` class which uses `preview` internally. Note that the `border` option is only available since v0.4 2011/02/28. Before that you would need to set `\PreviewBorder` manually.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle x=3+y^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: your solution works perfect for one line equations but not for multiline expressions (split, gather, ...). At least I don't know how to do it. May be my minimal working example was too minimal.

Comment: You can use `aligned`, `gathered`, and `alignedat` as alternatives; I don't think there's an analogue for `split` however.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,textmath]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
$x=3+y^2$
\end{document}
```

Use `textmath` option instead of `displaymath` and use $ ... $ math environment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the *tightpage* option of the *preview* LaTeX package crops the page only vertically but doesn't crop horizontally. Even the `-T tight` option of *dvipng* doesn't help. *dvipng* prints the following warning: ***preview-latex tightpage option detected, will use its bounding box***.

If you want to tightly crop the page horizontally you should use the *standalone* LaTeX package instead of the *preview* package:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,preview,varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ x = 3 + y^2 \]
\end{document}
```

The *standalone* package removes the left and the right space around LaTeX formula:

[image: 1]

If the *LaTeX* equation is too long and doesn't fit the page you can increase the width of the page:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,preview,varwidth=1000pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
```

But it is only applicable to PDF documents. The width of PNG images is always unlimited.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!