# Subcaption formatting changes when using standalone documentclass

Tags: subfloats, standalone

I have the same issue as in the thread [Crop a float containing subfigures horizontally with Preview or Standalone package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79877/crop-a-float-containing-subfigures-horizontally-with-preview-or-standalone-packa) but I want to place a subcaption next to the subfigure numbering. However this causes some strange behavior (see example). When I change the documentclass to article it works as expected.

Modified example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[labelfont=footnotesize,labelformat=parens,
justification=centering]{caption,subfig}

\begin{document}

\def\FigSize{.23}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[A]
  {
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  }
  \subfloat[B]
  {
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how the [varwidth] option woks, but it seems to have a number of peculiar results.  Put the figure inside a minipage (default article is 345pt wide) instead.  This will also show you when you figure is too wide.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I put the figure inside a minipage but it changed only the width of the output. The colon is still present.

Comment: Did you lose the [varwidth] option?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your answer. Removing the [varwidth] option fixes the formatting and colon but now the pdf page size does not fit with the figure size.

Comment: BTW, (almost) every time you end a line with { or } instead of {% or }% you wind up adding a space (hence the gaps around your images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create my own version of `varwidth`.  The hard part was getting it to work on things like `\newline` (not actually used here).  `\\` seems to work, but generates an error message.

As far as I can tell, `\FigSize` does nothing.  It is certainly **not** used by the subfig package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[labelfont=footnotesize,labelformat=parens,
justification=centering]{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\maxwidth}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{fakefigure}[1][]{\def\@captype{figure}%
  \def\newline{\egroup% end of previous \sbox1
    \ifdim\wd1>\maxwidth \global\maxwidth=\wd1\fi
    \sbox1\bgroup}
  \let\par=\newline
  \sbox1\bgroup\BODY\egroup
  \ifdim\wd1>\maxwidth \global\maxwidth=\wd1\fi
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\fakecaption}[2][]{\relax}

\NewEnviron{varwidth}{\bgroup% compute max width
  \let\figure=\fakefigure
  \let\endfigure=\endfakefigure
  \let\caption=\fakecaption
  \global\maxwidth=0pt
  \sbox0{\BODY}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\maxwidth \global\maxwidth=\wd0\fi
\egroup% restore defaults
\begin{minipage}{\maxwidth}
\BODY
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}
\def\FigSize{.23}% no known function
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[A]
  {
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  }
  \subfloat[B]
  {
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you! It's a bit beyond my TeX level but it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `varwidth` package redefines the LaTeX kernel macros `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` in a way incompatible to the original definition. Especially `\@bsphack` opens a TeX group and `\@esphack` closes a TeX group now. Unfortunately `\captionsetup` uses these macros internally so it doesn't matter what caption options you set, they are always set within an own group now and therefore are worthless since at the end of `\captionsetup` the options are gone when the `varwidth` package (which is actually more a dirty hack than a package) is used.

An example document:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{textfont=bf,labelsep=space,labelformat=parens}% This is all without effect!
  \caption{Hello!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If anybody is interested in a fix, please fill a bug report at https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues and I'll adapt the `caption` package to the `varwidth` package within the very next days.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, `subcaption` works with `\pbox`.

Embracing the figure inside a `\pbox` should work, but not in standalone.
There is an additional `:` with `varwidth`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{varwidth,pbox}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} % Figure larger than the page
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\mbox{%
\begin{subfigure}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{B}
\end{subfigure}
}}
\caption{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} % Figure larger than the page
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\pbox{1.3\textwidth}{%
\begin{subfigure}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{B}
\end{subfigure}
}}
\caption{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} % Figure larger than the page
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{varwidth}{1.3\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{varwidth}}
\caption{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]