# TikZ to non-PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, conversion, standalone

How do I tell TikZ to output to a standalone image file? Like JPG, PNG, etc?

Yes, there is a way to output it to PDF, then do a snapshot. But this is for mathematical-visual comparisons, and I need precision trimming so that I can put the images side-by-side in a Word document.

Here's a sample using the `standalone` class. It only takes care of the length, but the width stays the same as the `textwidth`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=0.5] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want the whole PDF to be trimmed to the edges of the `tikzpicture`. Or, even better, trim the PDF so that that I can leave (custom) margins around the graphic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile a latex document into a png image that's as short as possible.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible)

Comment: There are some possibilities to get only a picture but with pdf format. Then you need to use extern tool to transform the pdf file into a png or jpg file. I think you can find some links about this question.

Comment: @Caramdir: The duplicate you mentioned only takes care of the length of the `standalone`. Anyway, knowing better now from that other question, I'll edit my question.

Comment: The other one that you should look at is [How can I create a pdf document exactly as big as my tikz picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452/86).

Comment: Now that I see Martin's solution, I must admit that I would never have guessed that that was the problem!  I suspect that this will now get closed as a duplicate (and maybe be merged with that other question), but this is definitely a valuable piece of information to have on this site.  So good question!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have empty lines between the `document` and `tikzpicture` environment which puts the picture in an paragraph (which is `\textwidth` wide). Simply removing the lines fixes this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=0.5] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The rest of your question is already answered in
[Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible/11880#11880).

In short:

```
pdflatex file
convert -density 300 file.pdf -quality 90 file.png
```

or with v1.0 of the `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
```

compile with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape file
```

You might also want to use the new `border` option to set the border to `0pt`.

Comment: With `preview`, we have  some options like `activ`, `pdftex`  Is it possible to use the same options with the `standalone` class directly ? And  we can fix the border `\setlength\PreviewBorder{...}` and we can make a choice between the environments with `\PreviewEnvironment{...}`, I suppose we can make the same things ?

Comment: @Altermundus: You could disable the use of `preview` with `preview=false`. This does effectively the same as removing the 'active' from 'preview'. The develop version has the `border={<dimension(s)>}` option which sets `\PreviewBorder` (one dimension) or `\PreviewBbAdjust` directly (two or four dimension, space separated). All other options are passed to the loaded class and are therefore global, so `pdftex` would be passed to `preview`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: standalone.cls from texlive 2011 appears to be version 0.4a - is version 1.0 available somewhere else?

Comment: @prettygully: It's on CTAN since yesterday. TeXLive has it as well now. Please use `tlmgr` to update the package. See http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html if you need help with that.

Comment: I made a short script based off of this answer, assuming you have figures in a file "figures.tex" wrapped in \newcommand definitions: https://gist.github.com/gangeli/6fdfebce8ab748a15ea5 . Useful if you need to convert lots of figures (e.g., my use case of moving a beamer presentation to powerpoint); feel free to ignore otherwise.

Comment: How do you compile pdflatex -shell-escape file in TeXstudio? I can't file the "-shell-escape file". Anyone knows?

Comment: As security protections go crazy right now, this is not possible on newer systems. If you get a weird error `convert-im6.q16: not authorized` then edit `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and change the rights for pdf, i.e. change `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />` to `<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF" />`. (add `,write` if writing PDF files is also required).

Answer (score 3):

*This is a complement to the [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13361) for the particular case of Windows.
This answer is not exhaustif, but gives a particular configuration that works for me.*

## Installation under Windows (checked with XP/7/10)

1. Install [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html);
2. Put the folder (something like `C:\...\Ghostscript\bin`) containing `gswin32c.exe` in the [`PATH`](https://www.google.fr/search?q=how+to+add+folder+to+path+windows);
3. Create a folder named `StackExchange` where you will put all your questions and answers for [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz*);
4. In this folder create a file `standalone.cfg` with the following content

   ```
   \input{standalone/standalone.cfg}
   \standaloneconfig{convert={ghostscript, density=700, command={\gsexe\space -dDownScaleFactor=4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=\gsdevice\space -r\density\space -sOutputFile=\outfile\space \infile}}}
   ```
5. Use as model for your question/answer in this folder something like

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
   % \usetikzlibrary{ }
   \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill[red] (0,0) circle (1);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

And now just compile your `tex` file with the option `-shell-escape` and you will obtain a `PNG` with the same name and "resonable" default size.