# How can I render a LaTeX document without pages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, document-configuration

Almost always, I simply render electronic documents, so I don't need pages. Also, pages make it difficult to arrange images in a document.

I want to draw TikZ graphs for my blog articles, and I don't want to see pages when I walk with graphs. I want vertically infinite canvas that the web layout provides.

How can I remove pages in LaTeX documents?

Comment: Something like `standalone` or `tikzexternalize`?

Comment: What is `standalone`?

Comment: A class which provides very tight boundaries, i.e. the 'page' is just th the content which has been typeset

Comment: Is there not a document class without pages?

Comment: What's the problem with a page? The content must be typeset somewhere. Where should it go to?

Comment: `standalone` and `tikzexternalize` seems to serve the purpose for TikZ. But, a web layout without pages would free me from page-breaking in general.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I assume he will want 1 page, which approaches (as much as possible) infinity in its dimensions?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen: That's what I had in mind too, but the extracting of images has to be done anyway, regardless whether they are scaled or not. For web content still `gif/png/jpg` is needed, as far as I know and `.pdf` only in an embedded viewer.

Comment: I want everything in a big page unless I typeset a paper book, and I will probably not typeset a paper book for many years. And, you're right. I need to extract a tikz picture as an image file.

Comment: @crocket I am not sure if the file size of such image with huge dimensions will get huge or not. Perhaps not if you output as a `png` which interprets the page's background as transparent?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I'm not worried about file size. How do I externalize a tikz picture as a png file?

Comment: @crocket You'll might find an answer in [TikZ to non-PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/tikz-to-non-pdf).

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I derived my own answer from the link.

Comment: this might be useful: [Is there a way to make “page” size match document length?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49686/579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I derived an answer from [TikZ to non-PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/tikz-to-non-pdf)

```
% blah.tex
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {ok};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`[convert]` option to standalone class requires `convert` from ImageMagick and `-shell-escape` option to be passed to `pdflatex`.

Comment: Why do you use the `external` library?

Comment: I didn't know `[convert]` clashes with `external` library.

Comment: If you run `pdflatex -shell-escape` with the `convert` option you get a `pdf` AND a `png`. The  `external` library outputs a `pdf` every time it sees a `tikzpicture` that is to be used in a document if you have many pictures to reduce typesetting time.

Comment: Did not you install anything to get the png image? I recall I had to install `Image Magick` to get the png. I think this is something to include in your answer.