# tikz to png won't work

Tags: tikz-external, png

I am trying to convert a TikZ file to `png` following this answer to a similiar question: [TikZ to non-PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/tikz-to-non-pdf).

This is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=0.5] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In my `log` file I get the following error message:

```
(Ext.aux)
runsystem(imgconvert -density 300 Ext.pdf -resize 1080x800 -quality 90 
Ext.png)
...executed.



 Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
 (standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
 (standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

 ) )
```

My version of the standalone package:

```
Document Class: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files stand alone
```

I compiled it with the following command

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Ext.tex
```

I installed ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16, it is installed under: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16

Do I have to somehow set some path-variable?  I can't find anything online where I am told that I have to set the path variable.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to add the Image Magick installation directory to the `PATH` Variable. You can easily check with `where imgconvert` in the windows commandline if the `imgconvert` program is found in your `PATH`.

If the installation path of Image Magick is returned, imgconvert is callable.

Otherwise you have to modify the `PATH` variable. Here is a short guide for [adding a directory to the `PATH` variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx).