# Is it possible to output pgf plots and/or tikz into an image file like jpg or png?

Tags: tikz-pgf, png, convert

I'm trying to put simple figures made with Tikz into a blogger blog, which seems to require images to be in png or jpg, not pdf. I've tried using Snip and TikzEdt, but my final images are blurry.

Is there a simple way to copy paste the figures, or even compile the tex tikz code right on the blog? How do LaTeX bloggers usually handle this? Do I need to learn HTML to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Use the `standalone` class. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13361 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880.

Comment: There are scripts which can convert your PDF output to other formats, e.g., `pdftocairo`, `convert` (from ImageMagick), `sam2p`, etc. Also Inkscape and Gimp have converters built in.

Comment: Okay, I made it this far, I can see where I can increase the image file size for better quality. But what is pdflatex -shell-escape file?
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=0.5] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: Just increase the `density` (I am not sure you need the `size`).